# Jdbc loses parameter while calling Oracle stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle12c

I have following jdbcCall:

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = simpleJdbcCallFactory.create()
                .withProcedureName("MY_PROCEDURE")
                .withReturnValue()
                .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("TAB1_CNT", Types.NUMERIC),
                        new SqlOutParameter("TAB2_CNT", Types.NUMERIC));
simpleJdbcCall.execute();
```

It should call the following stored procedure:

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE  (
    TAB1_CNT            OUT NUMBER,
    TAB2_CNT            OUT NUMBER
) IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    select count(*) into TAB1_CNT from TAB_ONE;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TAB_ONE';
    select count(*) into TAB2_CNT from TAB_TWO;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM TAB_TWO';
END;
```

The function is working, if called via SQL, however, `simpleJdbcCall.execute()` throws following exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{? = call MY_PROCEDURE(?)}];
```

Why doesn't jdbc pass both parameters, and what is my mistake here?

Comment: `withReturnValue()`. Your procedure doesn't have return value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I thought, taht out parameters are exatly the return value. However. In this case JDBC doesn't close the transaction and I get another exception: `ORA-06519: Aktive lokale Transaktion erkannt und Rollback durchgeführt`. Is there any way to tell JDBC to close transaction after call without having to return values out of the function?

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed by [talex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3656904/talex), this procedure doesn't return anything, so `withReturnValue()` is not applicable here. However, without it you'll gonna get `ORA-06519` error, indicating, that there is an open transaction. The reason of it is the sql statement I provided. `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is only applicable to the DDL queries, where `DELETE` does not belong to, unlike `TRUNCATE`.